# Sending Data Back to an AlertDialog's Host

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

**To the point:** what is the *best* way to send data inputted into an AlertDialog back to the host of the AlertDialog?

I have an AlertDialog which is created by a DialogFragment created in the MainActivity of my Android application. It has OK and cancel buttons, and uses a custom layout simply to display an EditText box. When the user hits OK, the contents of the EditText box should be sent to a method in the host activity of the Dialog, MainActivity.

I've accomplished this by creating a listener in the DialogFragment that gets implemented in the MainActivity. The listener gets invoked and the activity receives the DialogInterface and a String from the EditText. It works fine, but it seems awfully complicated code-wise for what seems like something that should be able to be accomplished without much extra code in the onClick method of the Dialog.

Is this really the best way to pass back a simple command, such as running a single method with an argument in the host Activity? Or even just changing the value of a variable of the host activity? If I wanted to use more than one class of DialogFragment in the same activity. I would have to implement another listener, and make sure the methods in each don't have the same names?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This is a pattern that fragments and host activity communicate each other. An other way plz try "Otto event bus". Google it you can find some.

Comment: it's a pattern. but is it really the _best_ one for this common use case? I don't want to be using any external libraries at this point in learning how to develop…